# Taking address of the temporary in same piece of code - always safe?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, pointers, variables

I need to test some code, and methods accepts pointers to objects. As I want to write many tests, simplified my tests looks like this

```
bool addPoint(Point* point);

EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint(&Point(0, 0, 0)));
EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint(&Point(-10, 0, 0)));
EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint(&Point(0, -10, 0)));
//and so on
```

It works fine. I know that taking address of the temporary variable isn't a good style, but otherwise I will need to type much more, creating proper Point objects and passing them into test.

As far as I know taking address of the temporary isn't UB, so I can rely that my tests will always works as they works now? Or there are some other downsides of taking address of the temporary?

Comment: `&Point(0, 0, 0)` should not compile unless `Point` has an overloaded `operator &`.  https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.op#3

Comment: "*I know that taking address of the temporary variable isn't a good style*" - it is not just bad style, it is technically illegal, the code should not even compile under normal conditions. You are probably using a compiler that allows it as a non-standard extension. In this case, I would simply introduce a helper overload, eg: `bool addPoint(Point point) { return addPoint(&point); }` or `bool addPoint(const Point &point) { return addPoint(const_cast<Point*>(&point)); }` or `bool addPoint(int x, int y, int z) { Point point(x, y, z); return addPoint(&point); }` ...

Comment: ... And then you can drop the `&` in your `addPoint()` calls, eg: `EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint(Point(0, 0, 0))); EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint(Point(-10, 0, 0))); EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint(Point(0, -10, 0))); //and so on` or `EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint({0, 0, 0})); EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint({-10, 0, 0})); EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint({0, -10, 0})); //and so on` or `EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint(0, 0, 0)); EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint(-10, 0, 0)); EXPECT_TRUE(addPoint(0, -10, 0)); //and so on`

Comment: This issue can go away by passing parameters by reference, or constant reference if the parameter is not modified.

Comment: @NathanOliver it compiles on MS VS, Point don't have any overloads.

Comment: It [fails in MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/93o9477EW) when compiled with `/Za` (disable language extensions). In any case, taking an address of a temporary is not valid C++, and is best avoided even if your compiler happens to accept it as a non-standard extension.